# How do I copy data from google forms sheets to other sheets using script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I'm trying to copy data from a google forms table into a more "Front-End" table using script.

It all works basically fine except that if I reload the page more than once, some data gets pushed down a few rows every time I reload.

The first 4 columns are copied from table "RAW" into "FRONT" but the last 4 columns are just sorted along with the first 4. These are also the ones that kinda "don´t stick" to their counterpart on the first 4 columns.

Is that a problem with checkboxes?

After the first reload(how it should look):

[image]

After the second reload:

[image]

The RAW sheet looks weird as well... why does the google-form enter data that far down?

[image]

```
function onOpen() {

  fillSheet();
  sortSheet();
  colorize();

}

//fill FRONT sheet with data from RAW sheet

function fillSheet(){

  //get active sheet
  var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  //align column 1
  var fillRange_employee = sheet.getRange("FRONT!A4:A" + sheet.getLastRow());
  var copyRange_employee = sheet.getRange("RAW!B2:B" + sheet.getLastRow());

  //align column 2
  var fillRange_task = sheet.getRange("FRONT!B4:B" + sheet.getLastRow());
  var copyRange_task = sheet.getRange("RAW!C2:C" + sheet.getLastRow());

  //align column 3
  var fillRange_timestamp = sheet.getRange("FRONT!C4:C" + sheet.getLastRow());
  var copyRange_timestamp = sheet.getRange("RAW!A2:A" + sheet.getLastRow());

  //align column 4
  var fillRange_priority = sheet.getRange("FRONT!D4:D" + sheet.getLastRow());
  var copyRange_priority = sheet.getRange("RAW!D2:D" + sheet.getLastRow());

  //style 
  copyRange_priority.setHorizontalAlignment("center");
  copyRange_priority.setVerticalAlignment("center");


  //copy-paste
  copyRange_employee.copyTo(fillRange_employee);
  copyRange_task.copyTo(fillRange_task);
  copyRange_timestamp.copyTo(fillRange_timestamp);
  copyRange_priority.copyTo(fillRange_priority);


}

//colorize "priority" column
function colorize(){

  var i = 4;

  //get active sheet
  var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  //loop through column until no entries
  while(sheet.getRange("FRONT!D"+ i).getValue() != ""){

    //set different colors
    if(sheet.getRange("FRONT!D"+ i).getValue() == "[1]"){
      sheet.getRange("FRONT!D"+ i).setBackground("#FA5858");

    }else if(sheet.getRange("FRONT!D"+ i).getValue() == "[2]"){
      sheet.getRange("FRONT!D"+ i).setBackground("#FE9A2E");

    }else if(sheet.getRange("FRONT!D"+ i).getValue() == "[3]"){
      sheet.getRange("FRONT!D"+ i).setBackground("#FAF332");

    }else if(sheet.getRange("FRONT!D"+ i).getValue() == "[4]"){
      sheet.getRange("FRONT!D"+ i).setBackground("#89FA7F");

    }else if(sheet.getRange("FRONT!D"+ i).getValue() == "[5]"){
      sheet.getRange("FRONT!D"+ i).setBackground("#68ADF8");

    }

    i++;
  }
}

//sort sheet
function sortSheet(){

  //get active sheet
  var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  //get sorting range
  var sortRange=sheet.getRange("FRONT!A4:H" + sheet.getLastRow());

  //sort
  sortRange.sort([{column: 4, ascending: true},{column: 1, ascending: true}]);
}
```

Comment: "Reloading" the page executes the onOpen functions again. Are you sure you do not want to execute them manually?

Comment: It would be nice if it reloads "automatically" to keep the sheet always sorted. The main reason I did this by script was that no user would have to set any filters by them self and because the last 4 columns aren't connected to the G Forms sheet, thus they cannot be sorted alongside the first 4. Executing the script manually should end up with the same result anyway doesn't it? Maybe a "clear all" before filling again could work...